# Keycloak container kcadmin error: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed

Tags: keycloak, connection-refused

I run a docker keycloak container. It starts properly based on shell output. After it starts, I can access it from web brower which is out of host.

However, when I go into the keycloak container and try to run some cmd through `kcadmin`

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user $KEYCLOAK_USER --password $KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
```

I got the error :

```
Failed to send request - Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

It looks like jboss refuse the request. But as I said, I can access keycloak from external brower.
In this case, what log or something else should I check?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out it is my fault which I put the entry point in my dockerfile same as the keycloak image entry point, which the base image is keycloak image too.

After I remove the entry point in my docker file and rebuild, it works properly.

Comment: can you please explain your solution bit more?